# 'Widget' is not a subtype of 'Widget' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-3.10

I'm getting the following error during the testing of my frontend app.

> 'Widget' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Here is the detailed trace shown in the console :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<User>(dirty, state:
_StreamBuilderBaseState<User, AsyncSnapshot<User>>#aebd2):
type '({required BuildContext context, required Post post, required String postIdentifier, required
KNPostDisplayContext displayContext, required (Post) => void onPostDeleted}) => Widget' is not a
subtype of type '({BuildContext context, KNPostDisplayContext displayContext, (Post) => void
onPostDeleted, Post post, String postIdentifier}) => Widget' in type cast
```

Here the Widget code :

```html
  Widget _buildVisibleProfileContent() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: KNPostsStream(
              streamIdentifier: 'profile_${widget.user.username}',
              displayContext: _postsDisplayContext,
              prependedItems: _buildProfileContentDetails(),
              controller: _obPostsStreamController,
              postBuilder: _buildPostsStreamPost as KNPostsStreamPostBuilder,
              secondaryRefresher: _refreshUser,
              refresher: _refreshPosts,
              onScrollLoader: _loadMorePosts,
              onPostsRefreshed: _onPostsRefreshed,
              statusIndicatorBuilder: _buildPostsStreamStatusIndicator),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

On debugging, this is the line that is the issue :

> postBuilder: _buildPostsStreamPost as KNPostsStreamPostBuilder,

I upgraded flutter to the latest version : 3.10.1. My pubspec.yaml shows the following:

environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

I read other answers. Null safety is the reason why there is an issue but can't figure what needs to be done(maybe my lack of flutter knowledge). Earlier flutter versions didn't throw the error.

Help appreciated.

EDIT : upon request by rohan, I am uploading the post_streams.dart

```html
 
final KNPostsStreamPostBuilder? postBuilder;
 
 
List<Widget> _buildStreamPosts() {
  KNPostsStreamPostBuilder postBuilder =
      widget.postBuilder ?? _defaultStreamPostBuilder;
     

typedef KNPostsStreamPostBuilder = Widget Function(
    {BuildContext context,
    Post post,
    KNPostDisplayContext displayContext,
    String postIdentifier,
    ValueChanged<Post> onPostDeleted});
```

Comment: Just wondering what is `KNPostsStream`. I mean it's not flutter's default stream. So, please share how you're using `KNPostsStream` and `KNPostsStreamPostBuilder`.

Comment: @RohanJariwala updated the question with additional code. posts_stream.dart has lots of code pertaining to 'KNPostsStream'. Do you want me to add that as well?

Comment: can you share what is this `KNPostsStreamPostBuilder`? Is it your custom class or you're using some type of package?

Comment: @RohanJariwala custom class. More on this is here. https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/master/lib/widgets/posts_stream/posts_stream.dart. OB is jus replaced with KN as the prefix in all code. that's it.

Comment: @RohanJariwala The reference KNPostsStreamPostBuilder? has been updated in the question. Its part of post_streams.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the parameters of KNPostsStreamPostBuilder are optional.  However, the parameters of _buildPostsStreamPost are required.  Therefore, _buildPostsStreamPost cannot be an implementation of KNPostsStreamPostBuilder.

If you control KNPostsStreamPostBuilder, simply make its parameters required.

```dart
typedef KNPostsStreamPostBuilder = Widget Function(
    {required BuildContext context,
    required Post post,
    required KNPostDisplayContext displayContext,
    required String postIdentifier,
    required ValueChanged<Post> onPostDeleted});
```

In the original app, this function is only called with all five parameters supplied, so this won't break any usages.  You can also remove the explicit cast here and the null checks in the other two implementations.